# write a notSortedDescending function in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

Write Prolog code that defines a predicate notSortedDescending(Numberlist) that is true if and only if the list of numbers Numberlist is NOT sorted in descending order?

Could anyone help me solve this problem? I only know how to write a sorted function in Prolog. Thank you so much!

```
notSortedDescending([x , y | z ])  :-
                 ( x => y ) -> notSortedDescending([y|z])
```

This is what I came up with...

Comment: this is wrong in too many ways. work your way through a tutorial first.

Comment: The logic seems to be correct, but you need to learn prolog syntax. And `->/2` fails when the test fails. So you might need to write `.. -> .. ; true`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would write it in Prolog that compiles:

```
not_sorted_descending(L) :-
    \+ sorted_descending(L).

sorted_descending([]).
sorted_descending([_]).
sorted_descending([X,Y|Xs]) :-
    X @>= Y,
    sorted_descending([Ys|Xs]).
```

You need to cover the corner case that all elements are equal. If they are, the list is sorted descending so "not sorted descending" has to fail.

On its own sorted_descending/1 as defined will leave a choice point. Because you negate it this doesn't matter.

You can also take a more functional approach and use a left fold on the list like this:

```
not_sorted_descending([H|T]) :-
    \+ foldl(descending, T, H, _).

descending(V, V0, V) :-
    V0 @>= V.
```